# crosswalk project build for android failed

Tags: android, ant, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to build android app using Crosswalk. I followed this [official guide](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html)to set up.
And succeed in building [example project](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/build_an_application.html). But after when I try to build from my own HTML5 project, it builds failed.

ERROR Outputs:

```
Starting application build (arm)
 * Checking keystore for signing
   No keystore provided for signing. Using xwalk's keystore for debugging.
   Please use a valid keystore when distributing to the app market.
 * Updating project with xwalk_core_library
 * Checking for external extensions
 * Copying native libraries for arm
 * Building Android apk package with Crosswalk embedded (arm)
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:928: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:946: null returned: 1

Total time: 40 seconds
Command "/home/jian/app/ant/bin/ant release -f /tmp/Threecakes-Qqo589/build.xml -Dkey.store=/home/jian/app/crosswalk-14.43.343.17/xwalk-debug.keystore -Dkey.alias=xwalkdebugkey -Dkey.store.password=xwalkdebug -Dkey.alias.password=xwalkdebug" exited with non-zero exit code 1
```

This is my environment setting:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux
export ANT_HOME=/home/jian/app/ant

export PATH=/home/jian/app/ant/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux:$PATH
export PATH=/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/home/jian/app/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH
```

This is version information:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015

adb help
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

crosswalk version
14.43.343.17
```

And This is part of `ant/build.xml` where the error occured.

```
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
    <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
        <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package"
                versioncode="${version.code}"
                versionname="${version.name}"
                debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                buildType="${build.target}"
                ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
            <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
            <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
        </aapt>
    </do-only-if-not-library>
</target>
```

Why I succeed in building example project but failed to building my own project? And how do I fix this error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution finally ?

Comment: Unfortunally I didn't find the reason

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I downgrade version of Java to fix it :

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can report your issue to https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/ to get faster response from Crosswalk developer.